# Ideal place to deploy a springboot web backend and a nextjs frontend

Tags: spring-boot, next.js, deployment

I just wanted to know, if someone could suggest me some sites, where i can deploy my springboot backend connected to a mysql database. My frontend is build with nextjs/react.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Render](https://render.com/) or [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) if you don't want to operate a whole Kubernetes cluster.